# Convenient indexing to end of array

Tags: r, indexing

So I'm coming from Python where I can index until the end of an array by either omitting the end index. (Note that Python is 0-indexed):

```
In [1]: x = range(10)

In [2]: x
Out[2]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

In [3]: x[4:]
Out[3]: [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

In [4]: x[-6:]
Out[4]: [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

In [5]: x[-1]
Out[5]: 9
```

Also, negative indices start from the end of the array. In R, so far I've found that I need to do things like this:

```
> x <- 0:9
> x[5:length(x)]
[1] 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

and so on. Is there any sort of syntactic sugar for length(x)? (Perhaps something like `end` that MATLAB uses).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `tail` function instead of indexing.

In the following, the final 6 elements of the vector `x` are returned.  6 is the default return length for `tail` (and `head`, shown below), and the second argument changes that. So if you were to write `tail(x, 5)` for example, the final 5 elements will be returned.

```
> x <- 0:9
> tail(x)
# [1] 4 5 6 7 8 9
> tail(x, 5)
# [1] 5 6 7 8 9
```

Similarly, there is a `head` function for viewing the first few elements, which operates in the same manner.

```
> head(x)
# [1] 0 1 2 3 4 5
> head(x, 5)
# [1] 0 1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 2):

Logical indexing is one method. As mentioned (but not demonstrating the second argument to head or tail):

```
> x <- 1:10
> head(x,-3)
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
> tail(x,-3)
[1]  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
> x[x>=4]
[1]  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Mixing negative and positive indices is not allowed.